# Get the last transaction where date today is greater than 1 day in ms access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have this code:

```
    cnn.Open()
        query = "SELECT LAST(AnnualPayments.DueDate), Members.FirstName, Members.LastName " & _
        "FROM AnnualPayments INNER JOIN Members ON AnnualPayments.MemID = Members.ID " & _
        "WHERE (((DateDiff('d', Now(), AnnualPayments.DueDate)) < 1)) " & _
        "GROUP BY  Members.FirstName, Members.LastName,  AnnualPayments.DueDate " & _
        "ORDER BY AnnualPayments.DueDate DESC"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds = New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)

        Dim newRow As DataRow

        For Each newRow In dt.Rows

            MainForm.lstView1.Items.Add(newRow.Item(0)) 
            MainForm.lstView1.Items(MainForm.lstView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow.Item(1)) 
            MainForm.lstView1.Items(MainForm.lstView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(newRow.Item(2)) 
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        GetErrorMessage(ex)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
```

What it's supposed to do is show only the data if the due date is more than 1 day from the date today. Can you correct my mistake please. Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, are you looking for a day or a year?

Comment: Your title says 1 year difference, but your post and code says 1 day difference.  Please clarify which you want.

Comment: If the difference between the due date and now is more than 1 day, I want the data shown. Am using this to track the members that are due in their annual fee.